# Fastest way to get objects from s3 to ec2 PHP

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

On S3 I've got files around 100M (2.5M each) in this hierarchy:

id_folder / date_folder / hour_file.raw

I'm tried 3 different ways to fetch them ASAP:

I start with **laravel Storage facade** (I'm using laravel).. 
Storage::disk('s3')->get($filePath); -> this one is the slowest

then I google a little and i found this class: 
**Amazon S3 PHP Class**
http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/

I tried also to use Amazon instructions about creating S3Client and use getObject function and it still slow...

So, i need to get a lot of files from s3 to ec2 - what is the fastest way to do it? 
Thanx!

Comment: Coomunication betwwen S3 and EC2 is already fast

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding everything you're saying, there's not going to be a way around downloading that many objects being slow. 100,000,000 * 2.5MB = 250TB. That's a lot of data. There are things you can do to make it more efficient though.

If you try to get many (i.e thousands) objects "at once" by synchronously downloading them using [`S3\Client::getObjects`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#getobject), it will take forever. You get a little faster by using `S3\Client::getObjectsAsync` which returns a [`Guzzle\Promise\Promise`](https://github.com/guzzle/promises). This isn't really asynchronous. All requests to S3 do not execute concurrently. No matter what, calling `getObjectsAsync` will block the thread until the request completes. And simply iterating through a loop and calling `Guzzle\Promise\Promise::wait` will still take forever.

However, if you break up your requests and execute them in batches of promises simultaneously you can shave some significant time from your requests. Guzzle provides a [few options](https://github.com/guzzle/promises/blob/master/src/functions.php) to wait on an array of promises, but I prefer the `Guzzle\Promise\unwrap` function. It returns an array of the results of the array of promises given to it.

Below is a generator I've written that does just that:

```
public function getObjectsBatch($bucket, $keys, $chunkSize = 350)
{
    foreach (array_chunk($keys, $chunkSize) as $chunk) {
        $promises = [];
        foreach ($chunk as $key) {
            $promises[] = $this->getClient()->getObjectAsync([
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                'Key' => $key
            ])->then($success = function (Result $res) use ($key) {
                $res->offsetSet('Key', $key);
                return $res;
            }, $fail = function (S3Exception $res)  {
                return $res;
            });
        }
        yield unwrap($promises);
    }
}
```

I'm using this to download thousands of objects, and stream them to the user as they are downloaded.

The size of your batch is important. In the example, I'm executing 350 requests at a time. I've done a bit of testing and this seems to be the most efficient. In my tests, I downloaded 4500 objects from S3 using various batch sizes. I performed my test 10 times for each batch size. 350 seems to be most efficient.

But your specific use case--downloading 250TB of data at one time--will take a long time no matter what way you do it. And you'll quickly run out of memory if you don't save the files to disk, then you'll also have to worry about disk space. I'm not sure why you need to download that many files, but it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: How to use this generator? With foreach? foreach (getObjectsBatch() as $result) ?
I'm getting undefined function "unwrap()". Thanks!